# Angular - $q not working as intended / help waiting for $http to finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am working through my first Angular project (rails gem version 1.2.16.) and can't seem to figure out how to use $q correctly.

I have a directive where on click: 1. calls a directive function that calls a factory fucntion to run a $http request 2. uses the response from the directive function / $http in the template that is appended to the page.

DIRECTIVE:

```
d2jive.directive('getSpotifyTracks', ['spotifyFactory', '$compile', '$sce', '$q',
 function (spotifyFactory, $compile, $sce, $q) { 
  'use strict';

  var getTracks = function(artistName){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var spotifyTracks = spotifyFactory.getArtistTracks(artistName)
    deferred.resolve(spotifyTracks);
    return deferred.promise;
  }


  return {
    scope: {
      artistName: '@'
    },
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, artistName){

      return function(scope, iElement) {
        iElement.click(function(){

          var tracks = getTracks(scope.artistName);
          tracks.then(function(tracks){
            var t = '<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:trackset:Playlist:"' + tracks.spotifyTracks+ 'width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>';
            iElement.after($compile(t)(scope));
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }

}]);
```

FACTORY:

```
d2jive.factory('spotifyFactory', ['$http','$q', function($http, $q){

  var factory = {}

  factory.getArtistTracks = function(artistName){

    var tracks = {}

    var spotifyUrl = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=";

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var getTracks = function(artistName){
      $http.get(spotifyUrl + encodeURIComponent(artistName))
        .success(function (data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    };


    // tracks.spotifyTrakcs = getTracks(artistName);
    var spotifyTracks = getTracks(artistName);
    spotifyTracks.then(function(result){
        var trackArray = [];
        var tracks = result.tracks.slice(0,9);
        for (var track in tracks){
          grabbedTrack = tracks[track].href.slice(
            14, tracks[track].href.length);
          trackArray.push(grabbedTrack);
        }  
      tracks.spotifyTracks = trackArray;  
      console.log(tracks.spotifyTracks); 
    });

    return tracks;

  }


return factory;


}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="eventContainer row" ng-controller="VenueResultsCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="event in events">
    <h4>
      {{event.displayName}} 
    </h4>
    <p>
      <a href="{{event.uri}}" target="_blank"> Buy Tickets</a>
    </p>
    <div ng-repeat="artist in event.performance">
      <button get-spotify-tracks artist-name="{{artist.displayName}}">Discover 
        {{artist.displayName}}<br> -- {{artist.billing}}</button><br><br>
      <div class='spotify'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

THE PROBLEM: The template loads before the factory function returns the response.

MY SOLUTION: I created a function in my directive to call the factory and tried using $q to wait for the response before appending the template, but it does not seem to be working.

Any tips or leads will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to use some thing simular to this to get it to work:

```
d2jive.factory('spotifyFactory', function($http){
    var spotifyFactory = {

      var spotifyUrl = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=";

      getTracks: function(artstName){
         var promise = $http.get(spotifyUrl + encodeURIComponent(artistName))
                       .then(function (result){
           //this is where you modifiy the results
           var tracks = result.tracks.slice(0,9);
           for (var track in tracks){
              grabbedTrack = tracks[track]
                             .href.slice(14,tracks[track].href.length);
              trackArray.push(grabbedTrack);
           }  
           tracks.spotifyTracks = trackArray;  
           console.log(tracks.spotifyTracks);
           return tracks
         });
         return promise;
     });
     return spotifyFactory
});
```

and then in your controller/directive you would call this function like this

```
spotifyFactory.getTracks(someArtist).then(function(d) {
   $scope.data = d;
});
```

Comment: For some reason I had to move the code where I modify the results from the $http in the factory to the directive, but besides that your suggestions worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- $http is already based on $q. It returns a promise. So you don't need to wrap $http by a promise, it already returns one. See the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) with examples.
- your getArtistTracks function will return 'tracks' before the code in 'then' is executed, because that code is asynchronous. As you use async code, you cannot `return` the result. Instead you could:

  - call a callback with the track value you calculated
  - or, fancier nowadays, return a promise and fulfil it later (recommended, as it would give you a better understanding of how to use promises).